# Check if attr array contains any of element from given array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

I have a list of items Obj:

```
obj1.val = ["foo"]
obj2.val = ["bar"]
obj3.val = ["bar", "foo"]
```

And I have an array `check_list = ["foo","bar"]`

I know that code like `Obj.where('val @> ARRAY[?]', check_list)` will return `obj3` because it contains "foo" and "bar" but I want to create a function that will return all items.

I was thinking about some loop like: based on `check_list.each` but it just doesn't look good. How to make such a query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use the [`&&`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-array.html) overlap operator.

```
Obj.where('val && ARRAY[?]', check_list)
```

Tried out example :

```
development=# select id, group_ids from users;
 id | group_ids
----+-----------
  1 | {1}
  2 | {1,2}
  3 | {2}
(3 rows)

[arup@sampl_admin (master)]$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.3)
>> User.where('group_ids && ARRAY[?]', [1, 2]).pluck(:id, :group_ids)
   (1.0ms)  SELECT "users"."id", "users"."group_ids" FROM "users" WHERE (group_ids && ARRAY[1,2])
# => [[1, [1]], [2, [1, 2]], [3, [2]]]
```