# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a checkbox field (car_options) that stores an array of values for a number of selections.

I need to query all Car records that contain any of the values in another array.

["a","b","c","d","e","f"] that contains any of the following ["b", "z","v"]

#### Schema

```
t.string "car_options", default: [], array: true
```

[Check if attr array contains any of element from given array in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165716/check-if-attr-array-contains-any-of-element-from-given-array-in-rails)

#### My query:

```
 Car.where('car_options && ARRAY[?]', ["4door","3seat"])
```

#### Error

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: 
>   operator does not exist: character varying[] && text[]) LINE 1:
>   ...cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE (car_options && ARRAY['...^
>
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You
>   might need to add explicit type casts. : SELECT  "cars".* FROM "cars"
>   WHERE (car_options && ARRAY['BY']) LIMIT $1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL is complaining because `ARRAY[?]` ends up being a `text[]` (i.e. an array of `text`) where as your `car_options` column is `character varying[]` (i.e. array of `character varying`).

You could cast the array literal:

```
Car.where('car_options && ARRAY[?]::varchar[]', ["4door","3seat"])
```

or make the column `text[]`:

```
t.text "car_options", default: [], array: true
```

I'd probably go with the latter because PostgreSQL handles `text` and `character varying` types the same internally, the only time you'd bother with `varchar` (AKA `character varying` or `t.string` in a migration) is if you have a hard limit on how long they should be (and even then you could use `text` with a CHECK constraint).